# how to do popup window pass value back to the background window in android

Tags: android, return-value, popupwindow

I want to use popupwindow in my app.

click button1 can triggle the window popup,

click btnback in popwindow will close it .

but it failed in my program.

Also I want to send a value in the edittext which is in popwindow back to the backgroung window

how can i do it?
tks!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)

this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(

inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_setting, null, false), 

200, 
200, 
true);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_memo);

Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 

Button bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack); 

bt1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()

{

@Override

public void onClick(View v) { 

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_memo, listView);

showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 

}

});

bt1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()

{

@Override

public void onClick(View v) { 

pw.dismiss();

}

});

}
```

Comment: Take a look on this [tutorial](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/06/return-values-from-custom-popup-window.html). You may get help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the background activity be a listener of the popup window. When a button is clicked in the popup window, it will call a method say onButtonClick(String text) on the listener. Since your activity is the listener, it will get the text.

Comment: ooooooh.... can u give me some example? i'm novice of android. now i have 2 xml file: one is "main.xml" second is "pw.xml" and one main_activity.java. where should I write this code?

Answer (score 0):

on button click pass value from dialog to background window through a intent

Comment: ooooooh.... can u give me some example? i'm novice of android. now i have 2 xml file: one is "main.xml" second is "pw.xml" and one main_activity.java. where should I write this code?

Comment: if you want to call pw.xml from main.xml and send some data use this code..

-Firstly make main.xml as layout of main_activity.java.
-secondly declare another class suppose abc.class with layout pw.xml
and us following code to send data from one activity to other

    Intent i = new Intent(main_activity.this,abc.class);
    i.putextra("data",data_you_want_to_send);
    startActivity(i);

and then recieve this data in abc.class as:-

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value1 = extras.getString("data");

hope it will helps